# How to Integrate Laravel Passport (Laravel 5.3) in Lumen 5.3 or generate Oauth2 token with library dusterio/lumen-passport?

Tags: oauth-2.0, laravel-passport, lumen-5.3

I am trying to integrate Oauth2 authentication and found Taylor Otwell did a nice work for it with Laravel Passport. I am trying to integrate the same to create REST API, I google for integration and found a nice library for integration with link below.

https://github.com/dusterio/lumen-passport

I started work and follow the easy steps given by the author on github and composer package website. it starts and his given links are working.

I try to search over google but I do not found anything that show how can I integrate it.

But I do not found anything to generate token by providing username and password?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using laravel 5.3 passport then you dont need to use any other external libraries to create access token and generate clients for your users through username and password.

I have previously written a detailed step by step guide on how to make use of laravel 5.3 passport for your APIs and to generate access tokens agains username and password.You can read it here [Laravel's 5.3 passport and api routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525968/laravels-5-3-passport-and-api-routes/40393694#40393694) or ping me for any questions. Please vote it if the solution helps you.

Comment: Url listed are not working with the package given in the question.

Comment: Bro didn't get you.can you please elaborate a bit.thanks

Comment: I have integrated it in Laravel but not sure how to integrate in Lumen 5.3 setup.

Comment: I try a lot of code but still filling missing something. I search and try different codes but still no luck.

Comment: Can you share a git or something where i can take a look at your existing code base

Comment: OK sure I will upload my code on github and post link. thanks.

Comment: He is talking about Lumen, not Laravel

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Lumen you don't need to integrate Laravel Passport there is a lumen passport available on github

https://github.com/dusterio/lumen-passport

It will work fine with Lumen.

Thanks!