# Passport Password Grant Tokens Refresh

Tags: api, token, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport, refresh-token

I perform the steps described in this Questions:

**[Laravel's 5.3 passport and api routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525968/laravels-5-3-passport-and-api-routes/6#6)**

Everything works fine from the routes of the api, I can register new users, read their data etc etc.

Then add this command on AuthServiceProvider

> Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addMinute(2));
> Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(1));

i login in postman in url **{{url}}/oauth/token**

> Body: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> {
> grant_type : 'password'
> client_id  : {{email with which the user is registered}}
> client_secret : {{generate the client secret from the mobile app}}
> username : {{email with which the user is registered}}
> password : {{password entered by the user}}
> scope : '' 
> }

the response its successful

> {
> "token_type": "Bearer"
> "expires_in": 120
> "access_token": {{the access_token}}
> "refresh_token": {{the refresh_token}}
> }

I try to refresh token life time to one day send to **{{url}}/oauth/token**

## ref => https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#refreshing-tokens

in postman i send

Headers:

> Authorization : Bearer {{the access_token}}
>
> Body: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> {
> client_secret : {{generate the client secret from the mobile app}}
> grant_type : refresh_token
> refresh_token : {{the refresh_token}}
> client_id : {{email with which the user is registered}}
> scope : ''
> }

The expected response:

> {
> "access_token": {{new access_token}}
> "token_type": 'Bearer'
> "expires_in": 86400
> "refresh_token": {{new access_token}}
> }

But it does not work as expected, the response its

> {
> "access_token": {{new access_token}}
> "token_type": 'Bearer'
> "expires_in": 120
> "refresh_token": {{new access_token}}
> }

Answer (score 2):

Because you're generating `access_token` using `refresh_token`. So it shows the expiration time of `access_token` i.e 2 minutes which is set by this line:

```
Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addMinute(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you should be sending the client id (id field integer) from your oauth_clients table... not your clients email address

Answer (score 1):

```
 public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
        Passport::routes();
        Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(1));
        Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(1));
        Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(now()->addMonths(6));

    }
```