# oAuth Laravel API Route for Mobile

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

Our challenge is below for our latest project. With the advent of the Laravel Passport API we thought of giving it a try instead of using the old https://mattstauffer.co/blog/introducing-laravel-passport that I guess everybody was using prior to larval 5.3.

So our challenge is how to implement Laravel Passport for our mobile apps since we need to register users through an API instead of the VUE login element provided in latest laravel.

Any help will be mush appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Passport API as if now doesn't support creating the user credentials other than using their VUE view component . So there is no way you can do that. So if that is very important for your business/project then I would advise sticking to Javascript for creating access/api tokens instead using standard Laravel Passport oAuth implementation.

The ideal diagnosis for such issue is to implement your own logic of handling creating tokens and oAuth user in respective tables in Laravel.

Comment: Do you have any code related to the above which I can look and review ? or any helpful source material?

Comment: I dont know if it helps but I have a custom solution for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525968/laravels-5-3-passport-and-api-routes/40393694#40393694